# HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure. Is there an incompatibility between Windows 11 and .NET 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sdk

When I run my application, which is built with .NET 3.1, it generates an error

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
Common solutions to this issue:
The application failed to start
The application started but then stopped
The application started but threw an exception during startup
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028265
```

I think there's an issue with Windows 11, because the application runs on other computers.

I already installed the SDk's, and the issue still persists.